# What word “long-XXXXXX” means speaking a lot but saying a little?

Tags: single-word-requests

What word describes someone who speaks lots and says little, starts with *long-*, and takes six more letters to finish?

Comment: Your specific question has already be answered, but you can answer such questions for yourself by using sites such as [One look](http://www.onelook.com/). After a few tries to find the most relevant results, we see that [long???????](http://www.onelook.com/?w=long%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F&ls=a) gives the answer you seek.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is of course ***long-winded***, but this would fit better on a gaming and puzzles sites.

The OED also provides ***long-lunged*** as a synonym of *long-winded*.  Which one you want will depend on just where the other words in your crossword puzzle cross this one.

You won’t be able to use the synonyms ***long-breathed, long-tongued,*** or ***longiloquent*** because they have too many letters for your boxes, while ***longsome*** has too few.

Comment: If there's sufficient space for all of those words to fall and come to rest a short distance below the speaker's mouth, it might be long-chinded.

Answer (score 1):

Someone who speaks lots and says little is long-winded.

Comment: This answer was already given. :)